# SQL Alchemy Many To Many Filter List

Tags: filter, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I've got a many-to-many relationship set up as follows:

```py
user_role = db.Table('user_role',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(64))
    username = db.Column(db.String(128))
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=user_role, backref="users")

class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
```

Users can belong to multiple Roles and Roles can contain multiple Users.

I want to set up a query that returns only the `Users` who belong to a `Role` in my list. I already tried something like this:

```
role_list = ["admin", "premium"]
users = User.query.filter(User.roles.any(Role.name.in_(role_list)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE]
After a lot of research i found a way to do it:

```
role_list = ["Admin", "Premium"]
users = User.query.join(Role, User.roles).filter(Role.name.in_(role_list))
```

For my purpose I have to "DISTINCT" the result to remove all identical tuples. It makes the pagination work!

```
role_list = ["Admin", "Premium"]
users = User.query.join(Role, User.roles).filter(Role.name.in_(role_list)).distinct().paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
```

Now all admins and premium members are listed.